# Orthogonality of Chebyshev (Legendre) polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I used the recurrence relation to construct Chebyshev polynomials
$$
T_0(x)=1
$$
$$
T_1(x)=x
$$
$$
T_{n+1}(x)=2x T_n(x) - T_{n-1}(x)
$$
for $x\in[-1,1]$

I found that
$$
T_0(x) \cdot T_1(x) =0$$
$$
T_0(x) \cdot T_3(x) =0$$
$$
T_0(x) \cdot T_5(x) =0$$
etc. (numerical dot product, programmed in python)

I am pretty sure that
$$
T_0 \cdot T_2 =\int_{-1}^1 (2x^2-1)dx \neq 0
$$

in general
$$
\int_{-1}^1 T_i(x) T_j(x) dx=0
$$
only holds for $j-i$ is an odd number. Is this correct? I found the same result for Legendre polynomial. So, how they make a basis? This is not what I understand as orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal under the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)(1-x^2)^{-1/2}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Chebycheff Polynomials are orthogonal w.r.t to the following scalarproduct:

$\omega(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$

$$\langle f, g\rangle_{\omega} = \int_{-1}^1 \omega(x)f(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Legendre Polynomials are orthogonal w.r.t. the standard L^2 scalar product.

Comment: thank Snake707! I numerially confirmed the Legendre Polynomials case.